# Can't set up RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-recyclerview

Ok, I've trying to get this to work for past 4-5 hours with no success.

I've added appcompat as library and RecyclerView from sdk/extras/android/support

[image]

There's no errors here:

[image]

This is what my dependencies and libs look like:

[image]

I can import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView; to my classes and use them. I can make my own adapter and have no errors there.

But I can't use  in my xml. I always get

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
```

If I try to run my code, I get following error:

[image]

How can I resolve this? I've tried using RecyclerView in Android Studio, but I get same errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just try below:

In the view xml which contains android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

And make sure its parent container is not wrap_content.

And in the code:

```
private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.cardsList);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Comment: Coz you didn't post your code.  Just by guessing, I think if you give your RecyclerView match_parent, while the parent container of it uses wrap_content, it would cause confusion - might be this onMeasure issue.

Comment: Yes, indeed. In the end I just had to add those lines of code and I solved it half a minute after posting the question here. Thanks for help.